Javascript error running Rails 7 app on IOS iPhone/iPad
We have an app build in Rails 7 with a Postgres database and uses Bootstrap 5 for the UI components. Pretty basic but effective app.
The app works fine on Windows and Mac browsers and on most Android and Apple devices.
Unfortunately we do have a few devices where the app is not working. They're all iOS devices. An iPhone 11 and an iPad air. They're already paying a license fee for the software. So getting this to run in the older devices is rather important because I'm not sure suggesting them to buy new hardware will be received well.
What are the symptons? Well, none of the javascript is working. We found out pretty fast as the dropdown menus of Bootstrap or the Hamburger menu were not working.
I've tried a few things to confirm my hypothesis. I've added alert("Test"); in the application.js file and in other custom js files. The alert would pop up on the computer browsers, on android and on really recent iOS devices. But not on these older iOS devices.
How old you ask? One was an iPhone 11 with iOS 16.3.1. This one isn't that bad.
The other one is an iPad air running iOS 12.5.7 and when I go to software update, it won't suggest anything more recent. Even given how old these devices are, I think that's not the issue (entirely). More on that later.
I've also tried to add the following to my application.html.erb
<script>
  alert("Test");
</script>

The above works. It pops up on these older iOS devices.
Because they're mobile devices, I couldn't run inspect or any dev tools on them. I connected the iPad running iOS 12.5.7 to my MacBook to take a closer look. Once I got them hooked up and could see the console, I saw the following error pop up
TypeError: Module specifier does not start with "/", "./", or "../".
A quick search led me to the conclusion that importmap is not supported in older iOS devices. Based on this information it's definitely not supported by iOS 12.5.7. However, it should be supported by the iPhone running iOS 16.3.1 (But I don't have this one in my possession)
I found a few articles of people pointing out they had to revert back to using esbuild with Rails 7 in order to use older iOS versions. Fine, I reverted back to esbuild (Not an easy feat by the way). I was excited to try the app on the iPad, only to find out it still wasn't working. I first thought it was lack of ES6 support of safari/iOS. esbuild does not transpile the JS in ES5, only in ES6. But again, according to this, it should be supported. Even by iOS 12.5.7
I connected my iPad on the MacBook again and this time I got a different error in the console. That's the error that's leaving me puzzled and why I thought ES6 compatibility may have been an issue
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.' The error refers to a line in the bundles application.js file which appears to be coming from turbo
// node_modules/@hotwired/turbo/dist/turbo.es2017-esm.js
...
...
var submittersByForm = /* @__PURE__ */ new WeakMap();
function findSubmitterFromClickTarget(target) {
  const element = target instanceof Element ? target : target instanceof Node ? target.parentElement : null;
  const candidate = element ? element.closest("input, button") : null;
  return candidate?.type == "submit" ? candidate : null;   <-- THIS IS THE LINE ERRORING OUT
}

I've spent countless hours already trying to find an answer to the specific error or to "turbo js errors". That's where I'm at. Not sure what to try next. I thought about importing the css and js for bootstrap via CDN in my application.html.erb file but given the fact that the js is failing because of a turbo file, I don't think it would solve my issue. Could it be the version of turbo that's not compatible? Would it be beneficial to try and bump the version down? There's no doubt the iOS version is responsible for that. But not to the full extent I thought. It looks like that iOS 16 version should be compatible with everything. The iOS 12.5, although pretty old should support ES6. Any recommendation?

that line from turbo.es2017-esm.js looks corrupted. I checked the same line in my app and it's return (candidate === null || candidate === void 0 ? void 0 : candidate.type) == "submit" ? candidate : null; the candidate?.type in your file doesn't look like any javascript I'm familiar with.

Interesting. Is there a chance this turbo.es2017-esm.js has different versions?

yes, there are different versions. Probably you're using the turbo-rails gem, which has versions, and which has javascript module dependencies on versions of @hotwired/turbo. But the weirdness I'm wondering about is just the syntax of the line of js that your app rejects. I would suggest deleting @hotwired/rails and rebuilding with yarn add, or whatever build system you're using.

?. is the Optional Chaining Operator and according to MDN it's supported from Safari on IOS 13.4.
